# Why does HTTP use TCP?

Tags: http, tcp, udp

I suppose a way to paraphrase this question is why can't HTTP just use UDP? What specific functionalities provided by the TCP are explicitly required by HTTP?

Comment: packet delivery guarantee nedeed

Comment: and packet reordering protection

Comment: There is no 'packet delivery guarantee'. What there is is a guarantee that *if a byte is received,* it is the correct value of the next byte in the stream, with no gaps and no duplicates.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ordering, non-duplication, integrity, pacing of large payloads, ... same as anybody else needs really. There was a move some years back to provide HTTP over UDP for tiny payloads that would fit into a single datagram, and ditto the responses, but most HTTP payloads are too big for one datagram so the point is lost.

Comment: I didn't know about the UDP movement.  How would the client know that the response would fit in a single datagram?

Comment: @BrianWhite My guess is that the client could not know in all cases.

Comment: @BrianWhite Well that was the problem. The idea was to use it for requests like HEAD that have small request & reply payloads..

Comment: In hindsight this is interesting, because since 2012 the use of HTTP requests to GET and POST tiny quantities of JSON exploded.

Comment: @user207421 : so when we start http request/response (say from browser) - `TCP` session is created ?

Comment: @rahulaga_dev Of course.

Comment: ok, is there some default time duration for that session ? is this someway related to http 'kelp alive' ?

Comment: @rahulaga_dev The TCP session lasts until either peer closes the connection, which does indeed depend on HTTP keep-alive, as well as configurations and implementation choices at both ends. If you want to know more see RFC 2616 and successors.